# Perspective warp Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am trying to change the perspective of the following picture so that it appears as if it's taken from the right lane of the road:

[image]

What I have achieved so far with Perspective Warp tool is this (dont mind the blank space):

[image]

But the problem here is the road looses its sharpness and becomes blurred. However much I tried, sharpness filters do not give good enough results. 
Could there be a simpler way, to change the perspective without using the Perspective Warp tool?

This is what I've got so far by following KjP's suggested route:

[image]

I have also duplicated the left lane of the road and stretched it with free transform tool so that it increased in size. Needs more editing though.

Comment: Could the content aware move tool give you better results?

Comment: I doubt I can change perspective with it. It could extend the road though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Content-Aware fill (selected the yellow lines with polygon marquee tool, copied and then filled) like so (obviously with a bit more care):

[image]

Now apply the yellow lines yourself (pasted and summarily distorted, obviously with a bit more care again):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't distribute the lanes equally.

Comment: Hi KJP, I think it would be beneficial for people viewing this question if you explained what you did to achieve the final result.

Comment: @astralmaster you can make a new selection for the right side and distort the perspective or add another image with similar foliage to shape the road.

Comment: @astralmaster This image was taken from the center, there's no changing that. So you need to move more than the lines to make the lanes seem 'distributed". The grass on the left would need to get paved over.

Comment: @AndrewH Yes, I decided to edit the image like KjP suggested and then transform the left part of the road (stretch) to create visibility of "distributed" lanes. I'm going to post the end result plus steps.

Answer (score 3):

To finish off the effect. use the transform tool to shape the new road perspective.

This is a very quick selection using the pen tool to outline the right side foliage.

[image: tree selection]

With the new selection in a new layer. Go to Edit -> Transform -> Perspective.

[image: tree perspective]

There are a couple of different routes you can go with shaping the road. You can mess around with what needs to be selected. It might be better to just select the bottom part of the right side treeline.

[image: second option]

Or you can even find an entirely different photo to shape the road.